# Visual Studio - Clearing or resetting all pinned properties

Tags: visual-studio

I am using the [pinned properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/autos-and-locals-windows?view=vs-2019#pin-properties-in-the-autos-or-locals-window) feature of the VS debugger. However, a property that I have pinned causes an "Internal error in the expression evaluator." I can no longer inspect this object to unpin the problematic property or to view other property values. How do I reset this so I can inspect objects of this type again?

**Actions taken so far:**

- Deleted `.vs` folder from solution root

Comment: I have faced with this issue today. Removing .vs, delete vs temp folder don't work. How did you solve it?

Comment: Visual studio stores this data in ObjectFavorites.json inside your personal Documents folder: %USER%/Documents/Visual Studio 2019/Visualizers. Full answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64604918/976004

Answer (score 13):

I got the same issue today.  As mentioned above, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64540926/visual-studio-2019-error-in-locals-panel-during-debugging-internal-error-r/64604918#64604918) solved my problem.

Update your `ObjectFavorites.json` file.  Eg:

```
C:\Users\<userName>\Documents\Visual Studio 2019\Visualizers\ObjectFavorites.json
```