# Visual Studio 2019: Error in "locals" panel during debugging - "internal error retrieving local value"

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-2022

## Original Question

(For reproduction instruction see Update II)

I recently messed around with Visual Studio 2019 during a debugging session. I pinned some properties of the class "SqlCommand" as "Favorites". Since that moment I receive an error message "internal error retrieving local value" in the "locals".

There is a "refresh" button on the right of the value column, and when I hit it, I get the message "Internal error in the expression evaluator."

Now I am not able to unpin that specific property, because the class tree can not be opened anymore.

This behavior is not bound to a specific solution, I created a new demo solution where I have the exact same issue.

You can see it in the below screenshot:

[image: error in Locals window]

The **main goal** would be to somehow **clear the information** of which property of the classes are pinned in the "locals" window.

I already tried several things to get rid of the error.

- It seems that VS is somehow storing the information about which properties are tagged, so I tried to delete the "ComponentModelCache" in the AppData.
- I reset the settings.
- I use the repair tool in the installer.
- I deleted the *.suo file, and then I deleted the whole .vs folder.
- I see the same issue when i start devenv in /safemode.
- devenv /resetuserdata did also not help
- I examined the activity log, but there are no clues.
- I changed the Target Framework of the project from 4.7.2 to 3.5

I use Windows Server 2019 Standard, .Net Framework 4.7.2, Visual Studio 2019 16.7.6

I use the following code in the demo application:

```
private static int Main(string[] args)
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

    return 0;
}
```

## UPDATE I

This is the pinning feature i'm talking about. I show it on the example of the WorkstationId property of the SqlConnection object (because it on the SqlCommand it does not work anymore). I believe I used it on the command text and the parameters property. [The pinnable property is a relatively new feature introduced with 16.4](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2019/release-notes-v16.4#pinnable-properties-164GA)

[image: Pinning a property]

## UPDATE II: Reproduction instruction

1. Make a fresh installation of Visual Studio 2019
2. Create a new console project
3. Use the code that I posted above in the original question
4. Set a breakpoint after you created the Command object
5. Debug the project [F5]
6. Open the "Locals" window.
7. Expand the cmd variable and scroll until you find the "Parameters" property
8. Pin the parameters property (as described in Update I)
9. Stop debugging
10. Start the debugger again
11. Open the "Locals" window.
12. You see the error "internal error retrieving local value"
13. Hit the "Refresh" icon (it's the round arrow at the right side of the value column)
14. You see the error "Internal error in the expression evaluator" as described in the original question.

## UPDATE III (More experiments that did not help)

- I used "fix installation" from the VS installer.
- I uninstalled and reinstalled VS.
- I completely deleted the whole %USER%/AppData/.../VisualStudio folder

Comment: This question deserves more votes as it is such an obscure but still well presented bug.

Comment: I have the same problem on VS2019 after pinning one item in array during debug. And still can't solve the problem.

Comment: This question should be generalized to just "Visual Studio".  I found it with the same problem in VS 2022.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is a file called `ObjectFavorites.json` in the folder:

```
%USER%/Documents/Visual Studio 2019/Visualizers
```

It has the following contents:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://aka.ms/vs/debugger-managed-favorites-schema",
  "types": {
    "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand": {
      "favorites": [
        "Parameters"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**Delete the line `"Parameters"`.**

You don't even have to stop or restart VS, you can edit this file on the fly. Start the debugger again after you have removed the line and the error will be gone.

Comment: Thank you so much.
In my case, I overrode a property of a base class because the property name needed to be preserved but the data type changed.
And when I then made the mistake of trying to pin the literally 'new' version, it broke the variable view for the whole class.

Answer (score 2):

In my side, I did not face the same issue.

[image]

So maybe you could try the following suggestions:

**1)** right-lcick on your project **Properties**--> **Build**--> **Advanced**-->--change **Debug Info** to `Full`.

**2)** check the option **Use Managed Compatibility Mode** under **Tools**-->**Options**-->**Debugging**-->**General**

**3)** enter `C:\Users\xxx(current user)\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\16.0_xxx\Settings`

open each file and then search for this:

`<PropertyValue name="UseVBCSLegacyExpressionEvaluator">0</PropertyValue>`

**Then**, change the value `0` to `1`. Save the change, restart VS to test again. And also you should run it As **Administrator**.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for taking the time and help me with the issue.

Unfortunately it did not solve it. When I turn on the config *Use Managed Compatibility Mode* I do not see the error anymore, but I am also not able to use the pinning feature anymore. (I described the pinning feature in an update on the question.) As soon Is I turn it off, I can use the pinning feature again, but the error is back. The value in "UseVBCSLegacyExpressionEvaluator" is automatically changed back to 0 every time I close VS. I'm going to provide a reproduction instruction later today.

Comment: Hi Perry. I will check it again. Meanwhile, you can have a look at my reproduction instruction I posted at the bottom under "Update II".

Comment: Sure. I use Notepad to open every `vs.settings` file and then change the value,then click save. I try several times and then the value will not be changed since VS restarts. And I will try your steps.

Comment: I can now cofirm with the following steps: 1. Change the options. 2. Close VS. 3. find all *.vssettings files in the AppData...VisualStudio folder. 4. Open it in VSCode 5. Change it from "0" to "1", save it. 6. Open solution in VS, run debugger. 7. I can inspect the variable, but can not pin or unpin any property. 8. Stop the debugger, close VS. 9. Open the *.vssettings file again in VSCode --> the value is "0" again. 10. Open VS again, change options back to normal, start debugger, error is still there.

Comment: When you modify `CurrentSettings.vssettings`, you should make sure you have closed all VS at that time. 1. close all vs, enter `C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\16.0_xxx\Settings\CurrentSettings.vssettings` 2. then use the `NotePad` rather than `vs code` to open it, change the value an then click `Save`. Close that file, restart your VS and then changed value will  be used. You can uncheck `Use Managed Compatibility Mode` since you do want it.  Besides, follow your step and I did not face the same error as you described and maybe you could switch other PC to test it.

Comment: Hi Perry. Thanks again for your help. I was able to reproduce the exact same error on 2 machines: a Windows Server running on HyperV on a Desktop PC and a Windows 10 running on a Laptop. And I followed your instructions exactly and had the same issue: the value of UseVBCSLegacyExpressionEvaluator is always reset to 0. It looks as if we don't get anywhere from here.

Comment: Thank you very much Perry for your time and effort. I found now the solution (by accident).

Comment: @Chrigl, thanks for sharing the solution. Actually, it is quite amazing::)